# Use the WeightedBinaryCrossEntropy C#

Tags: c#, cntk

I'm looking for some info about the CNTKLib.WeightedBinaryCrossEntropy function. It takes the Weights var as an input. What exactly does this Weights variable mean?

I want to do do multi label classification with CNTK. I'm now using 
var loss = CNTKLib.BinaryCrossEntropy (m_fctModel, labelVariable);

But I want to replace this with the WeightedBinaryCrossEntropy. Is there any example with the use of this function?

(Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
CNTKLib.WeightedBinaryCrossEntropy(model.Output, labelInput, weightInput)
```

is identical to

```
CNTKLib.Times(CNTKLib.BinaryCrossEntropy(model.Output, labelInput).Output, weightInput)
```

where `weightInput` is an input variable with the same shape as `labelInput` that contains the weight for the given training sample.